# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CityCollectionCSharp.BRTDataSet.prop.get'

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have read many of the threads on here about this issue but I still don't understand why this is happening in this case.  I have used this exact code many times to pass parameters to open forms in the past but for some reason I am getting that error.  The error I receive is on line propTableAdapter.FillByBRTNumber(BRTDataSet.prop, BrtNumberKey); as it does not recognize prop which is a table in the dataset.

The code is below on the page that I am getting the error and please note that I did create an instance of the dataset but what happens then is the page opens during debugging but it appears the bindingsource never gets the query.  I have never had to do that way in the past including many times in this project.

```
public partial class frmBRTDetail : Form
{
    public frmBRTDetail(BRTSearch _owner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    public void LoadBRTNumberKey(String BrtNumberKey, String tableName)
    {            
        //BRTDataSet BRTDataSets = new BRTDataSet();
        propTableAdapter.FillByBRTNumber(BRTDataSet.prop, BrtNumberKey);
    }
}
```

The code on the page that opens this one:

```
    public BRTSearch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BRTSearch_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bRTDataSet.prop' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        //this.propTableAdapter.Fill(this.bRTDataSet.prop);
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //caseSelectorBindingSource.Filter = "BRTNumber ='" + textBox3.Text + "'";
        //propBindingSource.Filter = "PARCEL ='" + textBox3.Text + "'";
        if (textBox3 != null)
        {           
           frmBRTDetail BRTDetail = new frmBRTDetail(this);
           BRTDetail.LoadBRTNumberKey(textBox3.Text, null);
           BRTDetail.Show();
        }
    }

    private void dgvBRT_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
        BRTDataSet.propRow SelectedRow;

        SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)propBindingSource.Current;
        SelectedRow = (BRTDataSet.propRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

        frmBRTDetail BRTDetail = new frmBRTDetail(this);
        BRTDetail.LoadBRTNumberKey(SelectedRow.PARCEL, null);
        BRTDetail.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please format your code

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - I did it for him :)

Comment: Is `prop` static? You appear to be accessing it in a static manner and your error is reminiscent of static access of non-static members.

Comment: prop is a table in BRTDataSet.  Can a table in a dataset be static?  This is what I am confused about!

Comment: Well I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
propTableAdapter.FillByBRTNumber(BRTDataSet.prop, BrtNumberKey);
```

to:

```
propTableAdapter.FillByBRTNumber(brtDataSet.prop, BrtNumberKey);
```

Dumb mistake.